# Hibernate on Ubuntu 14.04 not working

Tags: 14.04, suspend, hibernate

Im running a dual boot with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. Im trying to get my computer to hibernate or suspend but cant get either.

I have a swap that is slightly larger than my RAM.

When running sudo pm-hibernate, my screen goes black for a second and the it comes back on right away. The same thing is happening with pm-suspend.

I tried sudo vi /etc/systemd/logind.conf and took out the comments on a couple lines, leaving the following:

```
[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
Controllers=blkio cpu cpuacct cpuset devices freezer hugetlb memory perf_event      net_cls net_prio
ResetControllers=
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
HandlePowerKey=poweroff
HandleSuspendKey=suspend
HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
HandleLidSwitch=hibernate
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
```

I've been trying for a couple hours but cant seem to get it right. Any help would be apreciated! Thanks!